# I want to know about http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/ how it force video to download

Tags: caching, proxy, download, youtube, youtube-api

I need some help about how savefrom force a video to download.
go to > http://en.savefrom.net/1-how-to-download-youtube-video/ 
add any youtube video URL it will show you available formats 
then on click it will force you to download this video ????

How this force to download??? Any logic behind this ?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. You have [**two Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994165/force-youtube-videos-to-download) at your other one.

Comment: But i have checked the both.

Comment: I have a python version solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65443895/how-to-input-data-via-a-post-request-using-requests-in-python/65650186#65650186